# handling iOS crash report- EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, cllocationmanager, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

I've encountered a problem with my app, if I let it running for 24 hours, after returning to it, it crashes. It is a location based app and should work in background for unlimited time. As you can see, the crash occurred in some "native" thread. Is suggests some faulty memory access?

The crash report is:

```
Incident Identifier: 37244DF8-8792-4686-9FB4-867559F8B520
CrashReporter Key:   07002531b592d4c6d047876998efef8745326d1e
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         Freight Alerts [2659]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/1AF70899-D23F-43E4-9398-4F206CD01325/Freight Alerts.app/Freight Alerts
Identifier:      Freight Alerts
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-09-12 10:29:08.076 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  1

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31301848 0x312f1000 + 67656
1   Freight Alerts                  0x0000c7f8 0x1000 + 47096
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33a097e6 0x339b2000 + 358374
3   UIKit                           0x30f78f0e 0x30e1c000 + 1429262
4   UIKit                           0x31171ac2 0x30e1c000 + 3496642
5   Foundation                      0x379bc92c 0x37921000 + 637228
6   CoreFoundation                  0x3711fa2c 0x37092000 + 580140
7   CoreFoundation                  0x3711f692 0x37092000 + 579218
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3711e268 0x37092000 + 574056
9   CoreFoundation                  0x370a149e 0x37092000 + 62622
10  CoreFoundation                  0x370a1366 0x37092000 + 62310
11  GraphicsServices                0x33860432 0x3385c000 + 17458
12  UIKit                           0x30e4dcce 0x30e1c000 + 203982
13  Freight Alerts                  -[SBJsonWriter appendString:into:] (in Freight Alerts) (SBJsonWriter.m:184)
14  Freight Alerts                  -[SBJsonWriter appendDictionary:into:] (in Freight Alerts) (SBJsonWriter.m:175)


Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312f23a8 0x312f1000 + 5032
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x30277ea4 0x3026b000 + 52900
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x30277bc2 0x3026b000 + 52162

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312f2004 0x312f1000 + 4100
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312f21fa 0x312f1000 + 4602
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3711f3ec 0x37092000 + 578540
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3711e124 0x37092000 + 573732
4   CoreFoundation                  0x370a149e 0x37092000 + 62622
5   CoreFoundation                  0x370a1366 0x37092000 + 62310
6   WebCore                         0x32a4ac9c 0x329a1000 + 695452
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x339c072e 0x339b2000 + 59182
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x339c05e8 0x339b2000 + 58856

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312f2004 0x312f1000 + 4100
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312f21fa 0x312f1000 + 4602
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3711f3ec 0x37092000 + 578540
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3711e124 0x37092000 + 573732
4   CoreFoundation                  0x370a149e 0x37092000 + 62622
5   CoreFoundation                  0x370a1366 0x37092000 + 62310
6   Foundation                      0x37931bb2 0x37921000 + 68530
7   Foundation                      0x37931a7a 0x37921000 + 68218
8   Foundation                      0x379c558a 0x37921000 + 673162
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x339c072e 0x339b2000 + 59182
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x339c05e8 0x339b2000 + 58856

Thread 4 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312f2004 0x312f1000 + 4100
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312f21fa 0x312f1000 + 4602
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3711f3ec 0x37092000 + 578540
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3711e124 0x37092000 + 573732
4   CoreFoundation                  0x370a149e 0x37092000 + 62622
5   CoreFoundation                  0x370a1366 0x37092000 + 62310
6   WebCore                         0x32a740d2 0x329a1000 + 864466
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x339c072e 0x339b2000 + 59182
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x339c05e8 0x339b2000 + 58856

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31302570 0x312f1000 + 71024
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3712363a 0x37092000 + 595514
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x339c072e 0x339b2000 + 59182
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x339c05e8 0x339b2000 + 58856

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31302cd4 0x312f1000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x339baf36 0x339b2000 + 36662
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x339bacc8 0x339b2000 + 36040

Thread 1 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000004    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x2fe80630
    r4: 0x00000001    r5: 0x2fe8074c      r6: 0x2fe8074c      r7: 0x2fe8076c
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x3e0b8060     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x0000016b    sp: 0x2fe8061c      lr: 0x30277eab      pc: 0x312f23a8
  cpsr: 0x60000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x1afff +Freight Alerts armv7  <6238e95d195a3818980dfcffdcbf9692> /var/mobile/Applications/1AF70899-D23F-43E4-9398-4F206CD01325/Freight Alerts.app/Freight Alerts
0x2fedf000 - 0x2ff00fff  dyld armv7  <77eddfd654df393ba9c95ff01715fd08> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30073000 - 0x300bffff  CoreTelephony armv7  <b8f80d5d594c31d2b5d8fba9fdedb7e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x3026b000 - 0x30281fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x30282000 - 0x30298fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x30299000 - 0x3029dfff  FTClientServices armv7  <21de970d7ebb3e7fb502a0a5451b0806> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x302aa000 - 0x302b3fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x30376000 - 0x30455fff  RawCamera armv7  <293f818ba6533dceae8b900b6ed3c887> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x30456000 - 0x30494fff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x30495000 - 0x3049bfff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x304c2000 - 0x304d9fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <696bb0630b19388da0d72e685bcf6e28> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x3050f000 - 0x3050ffff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x30532000 - 0x30538fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3055d000 - 0x3055efff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <6a8f2f33c7543808a0f4599101c3b61a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x30711000 - 0x30715fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x30716000 - 0x30756fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x307c6000 - 0x30b35fff  TextInput armv7  <8d7f24642c7634cc8e3a6e65f1dcd98e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x30d3c000 - 0x30d5ffff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x30d68000 - 0x30d7efff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x30db3000 - 0x30db4fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x30db5000 - 0x30dcbfff  EAP8021X armv7  <952fcfdec0633aff923768fca1a26fcb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x30dce000 - 0x30dd1fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x30ded000 - 0x30deefff  CoreSurface armv7  <97f871f09f503c98a6371c2b657430d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x30df8000 - 0x30e1bfff  MobileSync armv7  <e42604c550283f4aa517ae8f108b340f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x30e1c000 - 0x312befff  UIKit armv7  <cd513a2f22f53d698c3e10f6fe48a63e> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x312f1000 - 0x31307fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <311f379a9fde305d80c1b22b7dd2e52a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x31308000 - 0x3132cfff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x313b2000 - 0x313edfff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x313ee000 - 0x3141efff  ContentIndex armv7  <7a64670bb2ff3ee39ddee1dc1c72f92d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x3141f000 - 0x31477fff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31478000 - 0x3147cfff  Marco armv7  <8dea3e558fe534ff868fc92e215ce53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x31494000 - 0x314ddfff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x314e1000 - 0x314f9fff  Notes armv7  <724966ed5cd4395cb70f9c996b123f53> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x314fc000 - 0x31506fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x31507000 - 0x3152cfff  OpenCL armv7  <f4b08361179a3f6bb033415b0d7c6251> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x31532000 - 0x31537fff  ApplePushService armv7  <f424c0340de637c08bbeb4f3bd8c6eaf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x31538000 - 0x31539fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x3153a000 - 0x315aafff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x315ab000 - 0x315f4fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x315f5000 - 0x315f9fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x316e1000 - 0x316edfff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x316ee000 - 0x3176dfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3187b000 - 0x3187ffff  CertUI armv7  <f503892ef60e36108d28d8f9d6144d2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x31880000 - 0x318bffff  QuickLook armv7  <802b1092542a3017a0380632502610d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x3193d000 - 0x31943fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x31944000 - 0x31995fff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x31996000 - 0x3199afff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x319e9000 - 0x319f8fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <70ac33720f513f0f97ea2279260678ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x319f9000 - 0x31a08fff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x31a32000 - 0x31a38fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3227a000 - 0x3227ffff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <dc11c5c2cbe73a6288a6094ebf5de673> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x3244d000 - 0x3244dfff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x327e8000 - 0x327e9fff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x32874000 - 0x32883fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <a2363f8ed49932dba415d2d4cd32fb74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x3293f000 - 0x32976fff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x3297b000 - 0x3298efff  DataDetectorsCore armv7  <3f4596cbe1b13fdcb427d87de21df3f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x3299a000 - 0x3299dfff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x329a1000 - 0x33160fff  WebCore armv7  <2690c38c9c5f3c09975d619dd1dfbed7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x33163000 - 0x331adfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f1fbb825def23043830a095b953a9c94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x331ae000 - 0x331c3fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x33279000 - 0x33298fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x33299000 - 0x3329cfff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3329d000 - 0x332a0fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x332b4000 - 0x33311fff  StoreServices armv7  <6ce256d3cf433e4aa1af8d696bf1f75d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x335ac000 - 0x33684fff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x336f6000 - 0x33733fff  FTServices armv7  <3f23418319a03a589dd5cac7df20e238> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x33819000 - 0x3384dfff  MIME armv7  <d30292ea8f7e360fa5f5d5b1b62b602d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x3385c000 - 0x33866fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <cb64e146a8ee3fda9e80ffae1ccc9c5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3386e000 - 0x338a6fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x338a7000 - 0x33900fff  IMAVCore armv7  <ce90304da959333d81a64171a6ac3ae8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMAVCore.framework/IMAVCore
0x33901000 - 0x33909fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x33928000 - 0x33964fff  iCalendar armv7  <f2836083051132d3aa40ad82d7f73aea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x339b2000 - 0x33a3efff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x33a4c000 - 0x33a4efff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x33a59000 - 0x33a65fff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x33a66000 - 0x33ac9fff  IMCore armv7  <046b6b615a743057b59d4aaba8a91d61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x33aca000 - 0x33acbfff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x33ae7000 - 0x33ae8fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x33ae9000 - 0x33b93fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x33f57000 - 0x33f5bfff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x33f5c000 - 0x34009fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3400a000 - 0x342cbfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34319000 - 0x344d6fff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x344d7000 - 0x34500fff  AppleAccount armv7  <2ba44023410231fcb3f72f762ea3ce6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x346a6000 - 0x346c6fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x346d8000 - 0x346eefff  VoiceServices armv7  <c5b98e94eff33bf49006ff157c819987> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices
0x34835000 - 0x34839fff  IOSurface armv7  <443ac3aab9283da480dd9dcda3c5c88e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3484b000 - 0x3484bfff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x3484c000 - 0x3485dfff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x3487e000 - 0x349c7fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x34b9c000 - 0x34ce1fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x34d39000 - 0x34d3dfff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x34d88000 - 0x34d8ffff  MailServices armv7  <ab2388ce733e38b7a261273a401bbbf1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x34db7000 - 0x34e01fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x34e02000 - 0x34e46fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x34e47000 - 0x34f0dfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34f17000 - 0x34f4cfff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x3503e000 - 0x35040fff  libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7  <808518e0fbf539af8489f028ca5198c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x35042000 - 0x35047fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x3504a000 - 0x3504ffff  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib armv7  <3c1cc3175c403ace8fcbd3826bd43807> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/libGPUSupportMercury.dylib
0x3509f000 - 0x350b2fff  AssistantServices armv7  <4a0843742f363a8885b8db13b44ae256> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x350de000 - 0x3530bfff  MediaToolbox armv7  <c3098478486032c6aff336fa711c4fc6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x3530c000 - 0x353dbfff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <49607ffe4ee9389494285a213e392924> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x353e7000 - 0x3550cfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x35549000 - 0x35637fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3563b000 - 0x35643fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x35644000 - 0x35714fff  WebKit armv7  <3c5dd2ec46fe3e189c25bba78ad88fa1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x35715000 - 0x35874fff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <06a0a1ee488030169bdfab11fc8d2c5c> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x358a5000 - 0x3591efff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x35920000 - 0x35926fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x35930000 - 0x35932fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x35ccb000 - 0x35d00fff  DataAccess armv7  <89fd0c22338b37538cf61803a0bca9e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x35db9000 - 0x35dd6fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x35ee5000 - 0x35f21fff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x35f22000 - 0x36466fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x36467000 - 0x364b8fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x364c5000 - 0x364d0fff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x364d1000 - 0x36577fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <da424fecc66e3628ab03378ae80b38fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x36582000 - 0x36594fff  DataDetectorsUI armv7  <50ea319aaeb7307e92719980dd4b2953> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x36596000 - 0x365defff  CoreMedia armv7  <e274e1b894753b2eb05cf7b22a36d0c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3660a000 - 0x367eefff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x367f2000 - 0x367f5fff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x367f6000 - 0x36844fff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x36879000 - 0x3687efff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3687f000 - 0x36886fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x36887000 - 0x36a2dfff  CoreData armv7  <b0215b6d4d143859a2b313ecade095ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x36bcb000 - 0x36bd5fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x36be1000 - 0x36c0dfff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x36c0e000 - 0x36c0efff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x36c1d000 - 0x36c2efff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x36c52000 - 0x36d21fff  IMGSGX535GLDriver armv7  <fe4f330b9a433322844a0d87410b68f7> /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX535GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX535GLDriver
0x36d7b000 - 0x36dc0fff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x36dd4000 - 0x36eabfff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x36edb000 - 0x36edbfff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x36edc000 - 0x36edcfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x36edd000 - 0x36f76fff  EventKit armv7  <d67aa1508ee7306b8e2a45c76ffddff0> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x3701e000 - 0x3702afff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x37092000 - 0x371a9fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x371c8000 - 0x371cffff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <38132ecfd74b325fb1a4142bab663c19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x3726a000 - 0x3735bfff  QuartzCore armv7  <35d64a9da5523ae08c9e41511fd3061b> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x3735c000 - 0x3741efff  Celestial armv7  <19617260ee073e23b95e456d93930aea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x3741f000 - 0x37438fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x37443000 - 0x374f1fff  Message armv7  <573d0118246d3d9d8aed17e7ee2faec7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x37511000 - 0x37597fff  CoreMotion armv7  <6a9355d5a8e238b5b8f193605d509e15> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x375b6000 - 0x3762afff  MediaControlSender armv7  <87315c54b2293ab589950341ff91b45d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x3762b000 - 0x3768ffff  MessageUI armv7  <da7af4f9494b35558bf7892dfdb36ee3> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x37690000 - 0x376a4fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <54091a638f8731cd85ccf00fa06972c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x376c0000 - 0x376c3fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x376c6000 - 0x37709fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3770a000 - 0x37719fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x3771b000 - 0x3771bfff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x3771c000 - 0x37758fff  IMFoundation armv7  <253125b9103c3d13b66923ac6893c25b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x37769000 - 0x3776cfff  ActorKit armv7  <434c756a6b053f4ba3c954cfccddbf59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x3776d000 - 0x37833fff  GLEngine armv7  <6617f2b4ee283469a5595129889ff049> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x37834000 - 0x37841fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x37921000 - 0x37a9ffff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
```

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: First, symbolicate this crash log to see what's being called in your Freight Alerts app.

Comment: Please see my comment at "Sulthan" answer.

Comment: I have edited my question now and included the symbols using atos method, XCode failed symbolicating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a memory error. I suppose that the system thread is trying to call a delegate method but the delegate does not exist anymore.

Comment: Thanks, this is my thought too. I wasn't able to symbolicate the log, xcode do not do that for me. Using atos I receive only for the "13  Freight Alerts 0x00002e04 0x1000 + 7684" and "14  Freight Alerts 0x00002d68 0x1000 + 7528" the method and class (SBJsonWriter.m line 175 and 184).